# How can I do it ? I don't want to add same record in database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What methods can I use Find, FirstOrDefault, Any ....

```
public virtual void Add(T entity)
{
        using (MovieAppContext _context = new MovieAppContext())
        {
            var record = _context.Set<T>().Find(entity); // does not work I got e

            if (record == null)
            {
                _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I think one could determine what you want, but this question could use improvement.  Add more information regarding `Find` not working: what is `e`? if it is an exception, please provide that in your question. Also, don't pose potential answers unless you've tried them.  To that point, what have you tried?

Comment: oke I just want to add object for example  student.Add(new Student{name=Marc}) then I'm adding     
one more student  new Student{name=Marc})  ALERT-> sorry this student already existing    finally how can I achieve this event

Comment: Also, give an example to your usage, what is `T` what is `entity`; is it defined as an entity or inherits from it?  of course, this is really just symmetrical effort to improve your question.  The actual answer is `Find`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Any` all take delegate `Func<T>` as parameters

Answer (score 2):

Given your scope here, `DbSet<T>.Find<T>(params object[])` is probably not the method you should be using.

---

The following solution uses `IQueryable<T>.Any<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>>)`, a Linq Extension Method that accepts a Predicate\Function.

#### Code Sample using it

```
using (MovieAppContext _context = new MovieAppContext())
{
    bool queryResult = _context.Set<T>().Any((e) => e.Name.Equals(entity.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    if (queryResult)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Here, we are defining an anonymous function delegate, `Func<T, bool>`, that is in turn being used to define a Linq Expression, `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

---

#### Note

I defined this function predicate expression to evaluate on the entity names (a made-up property of this type; that in this example portrays a unique constraint.)

Also, an alternative to using anonymous functions declaration for this expression is to declare it, then pass it.

That looks like the following:

```
...
Expression<Func<T, bool>> WhereEntityNameMatches = (e) => e.Name.Equals(entity.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    
bool queryResult = _context.Set<T>().Any(WhereEntityNameMatches);
...
```

Which may help out with reusability and scope considerations.

Comment: I will try this method  _context.Set<T>().Find((x) => x == entity);  I can't  do this method  (x) => x.Id == entity.Id       because while I was adding a record ,İt hasn't Id value

Comment: that's understandable,  I meant for the `Id` to be an example of a property that is typically used for uniqueness\identity.   Whatever your means of identifying the uniqueness of the record is (why it would otherwise be a duplicate to add) should be part of the predicate.  So, it depends on the data.  Alternatively, no reason to check before adding if no such fields are unique, right?

Comment: ah... actually.. I may be wrong here.. I linked the wrong documentation.. I referenced to `List<T>.Find`, not `DbSet<T>.Find` which doesn't use predicates.. please update your question to include the exception or issue with using `Find`

Comment: I updated my answer; I am now recommending `.Any` method and providing an example of usage.  I don't want to go into too much information on Linq Expressions as it relates EntityFramework features.  It's not entirely relevant to the question or this answer, and there is a great deal to know on the technology and this framework's usage of it - as well as the framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

For consideration, An alternative here would be to not attempt the query lookup and check at all.

Instead, you would do a try-catch for `DbUpdateException` in the attempt to save changes after\following this `Add` operation.

```
try 
{
    _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
} 
catch (DbUpdateException) 
{
    var isRaisedByUniqueIndexOrConstraint = new[] { "2601", "2627" }.Contains(ex.GetBaseException().Data["HelpLink.EvtID"]) ?? false;

    if (!isRaisedByUniqueIndexOrConstraint)
        throw;

    // Could suppress and\or handle attempted duplicate record adding
}
```

This relies on those index\constraints existing, so you would first define a Unique Index on the column(s) (as well as your entity type using Data Annotations: `IndexAttribute`).

---

#### Note

Part of this answer\solution purposes getting the Error Number from ADO.NET SqlClient Base Exception to further scope and qualify the cause of exception.  The Error Numbers, `"2601", "2627"`, are hard-coded in this example.